# How to activate control box of a disabled form?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a form which I'm setting to disabled via `this.Enabled = false` on `Form_Load` if a certain condition is true.

However, this also disables the control box (maximise box, minimize box, and close box).

So when the form is disabled, i have no way of closing it since the close box is disabled as well.

Is there away I can disable the form but leave the close box enabled, so that I can be able to close the disabled form?

This forms' `OnClose` event also exits the application.

Comment: You can add panel to your form - and place all your components inside this panel. And disable this panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a small method that would be called if the condition is true and disable all controls/containers available in this Form.

Pseudocode:

```
    private void  Form1_Load() 
    {
       if(condition)
       { 
          DisableControls();
       }
    }

   private void DisableControls()
   {
        foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
        { 
            // your disable code here.
        }
    }
```

**edit**
This method don't take effect on the controlbox.

Comment: like JleruOHeP suggested in the comment to the original post, i already had a tabControl hosting all other controls on this form. So just used passed it to your DisableControls() method. Thanks